# How does your project handle the situation when feign calls the remote method to return to null?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-feign, feign

How does your project handle the situation when feign calls the remote method to return to null?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the status and error message attributes in response. In this case response may be

```
{
  "status": "error",
  "message": "Something went wrong, Report not found"
}
```